# How to change default call ui title and color in mesibo?

Tags: mesibo

I need to know how to change default callui title and color

MesiboCall.getInstance().callUi(this, mProfile!!.address, false)

Answer (score 0):

Change `title` in `CallProperties` to change the title

Refer here for the CallProperties class.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/calls/callproperties/
https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/calls/#call-properties---callproperties

If your UI changes are major, download Call App source code from GitHub and modify to suit your needs https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/tree/master/MesiboCall